# Why does datasource.server prints undefined in http get subscribe even though the returned data.length > 0

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a web api which is returning datasource list for a given userid.
The angular app is using this web api to get list of datasources.
Inside subscribe method, the console.log(data.length) prints as 2(as expected)
but console.log(data[0].server); prints as undefined.
I could not understand why? Any help would be much appreciated.
**postman output of web api**

```
[
    {
        "USERID": "user1",
        "SERVER": "localhost",
        "AUTHENTICATION": "WINDOWS",
        "DATABASE": "db1"
    },
    {
        "USERID": "user1",
        "SERVER": "localhost",
        "AUTHENTICATION": "SQL",
        "DATABASE": "db2"
    }
]
```

The datasource class on angular is defined as below:

```
export class Datasource {
userid: string;
server: string;
authentication: string;
database: string;
}
```

**Service**

```
getDatasource():Observable<Datasource[]>{
    let userid = this._authService.name;
    let params = new HttpParams()
    params = params.set('USERID', userid);
     return this._httpClient.get<Datasource[]>(`https://localhost:8080/api/DataSources/ByUserId`, {params: params})
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Datasource } from 'src/app/model/datasource';
import { DbService } from 'src/app/services/db.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-datasources',
  templateUrl: './datasources.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datasources.component.css']
})

export class DatasourcesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _dbService: DbService) {
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this._dbService.getDatasource()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data length: ' + data.length); //prints as 2 as expected(I have 2 records in db, so thats correct)
        //console.log(typeof(data[0])); //prints as object
        //the following output in debug window is 'undefined'?
        console.log('server[0]: ' + data[0].server);
        console.log('server[1]: ' + data[1].server);
      });
  }
}
```

[console.log output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO0o7.png)

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` and see what exactly are it's contents.

Comment: It prints as data: [object Object],[object Object].

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the output.

Comment: according to your api result the data should be accessed by: data[0].SERVER.
JSON is case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things could be happening:

1. The `getDatasource`-Observable could be returning a value that does not adhere to the `Datasource` object you provide (a pipe could modifying it).
2. The backend that the `getDatasource`-Observable is interacting with (to acquire data) could be returning data you're not expecting.

Here's a couple of suggestions:

1. As @MichaelD suggests, console.log(data), or even better use your browser to set a breakpoint in the beginning of the subscribe-function, and inspect what's "coming back".
2. Open your browsers network inspection tool, and verify that you're getting back what you expect (From the server). If you're using Chrome, from the menu click: `View > Developer > Developer Tools` select the `Network`-tab, and select the answer that's "coming back from the server".

Comment: Thank you MichaelD & @Anders.  The debugging showed 2 things
1. It returned the column  of the table which is diff from Angular class def
Table definition in db
(
S_USERID varchar(64),
S_SERVER varchar(64),
S_AUTHENTICATION varchar(64),
S_DATABASE varchar(64)
)

2. Secondly, the service returns the following format with the field names like the
following:

s_USERID: "user1"  
s_SERVER: "localhost"   
s_AUTHENTICATION: "WINDOWS"
s_DATABASE: "db1"   
Instead of first letter of the field in lower case, is there a way to get the output at least same as the database column names?